# OpenCV VideoWriter taking too long

Tags: c++, macos, opencv

I have a simple application using OpenCV 2.4.7 (compiled with gcc 4.7.2 in Mac OS Mavericks) to create a video from a collection of images:

```cpp
std::vector<std::string> filenames = ...; // image filenames

const int FPS = 25;
const cv::Size SZ(640, 896);
cv::VideoWriter video;
video.open("video.avi", CV_FOURCC('m', 'p', '4', 'v'), FPS, SZ, true);

if(video.isOpened())
{
   for(size_t i = 0; i < filenames.size(); ++i)
   {
     cv::Mat im = cv::imread(filenames[i], 1);
     if(!im.empty()) video << im;
   }
}
```

I am profiling just the command `video << im` and I have seen it takes longer and longer as the number of frames in the video increases. In the beginning, each image is added in less than 5 ms. After 10 thousand images, it takes 100 ms per image, and after 20 thousand images, around 170 ms. At the same time, the file "video.avi" is being creating and growing.

With another set of images (same size and format), I am obtaining up to 3.5 seconds per image after 10 thousand images.

My question is: is this behavior normal?

Comment: I have no answer but just an isolation question - if after many frames you do a new `video.open` does the performance reset? It seems to me that would help indicate what might be going wrong.

Comment: I guess if I reopen the file, I will lose the first part of the video.

Comment: I mean open a new file. The point being to check if the problem is that the slowdown is caused by many frames in the video or if the problem is caused by something else in the write method itself after it is called many times.

Comment: how big are your images? I'm trying to reproduce it with opencv on python and I get no slowdown so far.

Comment: Images are 640x896. By reopining the file, the execution time starts from some milliseconds again. So it probably has to do with the `VideoWriter`

Comment: I had a very similar problem recently on Mac OS, when I build the latest FFMPEG (I think 3.0) from source. Except for me, in addition, the written video files were empty. The solution for me was to install ffmpeg using `brew install ffmpeg` instead and recompile openCV.

Answer (score 0):

My setup may be completely different than yours but here is what I have. Can you post more details about your setup, codec, etc.?

- Windows 7
- XVID codec as installed directly from xvid site
- OpenCV 2.4.3

It doesn't seem normal to me. Below is a simple video writer with opencv and python. The histogram of write times for 10,000 frames ranges from ~0 to 2ms for 640x480 (black) images.

```
from collections import deque
import os
import time

import cv2
from cv2 import cv
import numpy

images_directory = 'images'
output_name = 'video.avi'
fps = 25
size = (640, 480)
is_color = True
frames_to_produce = 10000
write_times = deque()
writer = cv2.VideoWriter(output_name, -1, fps, size, is_color)
# writer = cv2.VideoWriter(output_name, cv.CV_FOURCC('x', 'v', 'i', 'd'),
#                          fps, size, is_color)

if writer.isOpened():
    for i in xrange(frames_to_produce):
        filename = os.path.join(images_directory, str(i % 10) + '.png')
        image = cv2.imread(filename)
        if image is not None:
            write_time_start = time.time()
            writer.write(image)
            write_times.append(time.time() - write_time_start)

print 'frames: {}'.format(len(write_times))
histogram = numpy.histogram(write_times, bins=5)
for count, bin_ in zip(*histogram):
    print '{0}: {1:.5f}'.format(count, bin_)
```

yields

- frames: 10000

and for frame count: frame time

- 1987: 0.00000
- 6108: 0.00060
- 0: 0.00120
- 1891: 0.00180
- 14: 0.00240

I haven't done a graph but I could if you want me to.

Comment: Thanks for your check. The codec I am using is the only one that I've seen I can use in Mac, and that was shipped with it. I tried with divx and xvid and the execution time seemed to remain stable, but no readable video was produced.

Comment: @ChronoTrigger Have you tried `-1` for the FOURCC argument and then tried all/some of the other options that you get with that for comparison? Regarding readable video, I found that it wouldn't complain even when it produced zero frames so watch out for fake completions.